# Required fields in scala map

Tags: scala

I have a jsonMAP : MAP[String , Any] and I am extracting three required field from map

```
 //case class for exception handling
case class ParserException(message: String) extends Exception(message)

 val Id = jsonMap.getOrElse("Id", throw ParserException("ID is required."))
 val Type = jsonMap.getOrElse("Type", throw ParserException("Type is required."))
 val Location = jsonMap.getOrElse("Location", throw ParserException("Location is required."))
```

If Json don't have required value exception will be raised.Is there any better way in scala to implement required field extract ?

Expected : If some field is missing from JSON , code should throw exception..If all mandatory fields are available program flow should move to next step.

Comment: it depends what is the expected behavior. Do you want to throw but make it for example shorter in code or you want to get an option or something?

Comment: I have edited details in Expected section.

Answer (score 0):

Lift the map to a partial function where missing keys are mapped to `None` and defined keys to `Some(value)`; for example,

```
scala> val m = Map("id" -> 1, "loc" -> 2)
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(id -> 1, loc -> 2)

scala> m.lift("id")
res0: Option[Int] = Some(1)

scala> m.lift("missing")
res1: Option[Int] = None
```

**Note** Lift once, viz. `val mL = m.lift`, query many, e.g. `mL("id")`